# How to make IOutputFormatter work in an ASP.NET Core Web API application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unix, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of learning C#/.NET right now and currently I am working on learning using C# in an ASP.NET Core Web API application. Right now I am having trouble using IOutputFormatter within the Startup.cs file of my project because it is currently giving me this error right now:

```
Startup.cs(39,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOutputFormatter' could not be found (are 
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
[/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/PracticalApps/NorthwindService/NorthwindService.csproj]
Startup.cs(41,55): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OutputFormatter' could not be found (are 
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
[/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/PracticalApps/NorthwindService/NorthwindService.csproj]
```

Here is what my Startup.cs file looks like right now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Packt.Shared;
using static System.Console;

namespace NorthwindService
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string databasePath = Path.Combine("..", "Northwind.db");

        services.AddDbContext<Northwind>(options => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source{databasePath}"));

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            WriteLine("Default output formatters:");
            foreach(IOutputFormatter formatter in options.OutputFormatters)
            {
                var mediaFormatter = formatter as OutputFormatter;

                if (mediaFormatter == null)
                {
                    WriteLine($"  {formatter.GetType().Name}");
                }
                else // OutputFormatter class has SupportedMediaType
                {
                    WriteLine("  {0}, Media types: {1}",
                        arg0: mediaFormatter.GetType().Name,
                        arg1: string.Join(", ", mediaFormatter.SupportedMediaType));
                }
            }
        })
        .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
  }
}
```

I have already tried adding "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;" however this created another error on "SupportedMediaTypes" at line 51 of the Startup.cs file.

Comment: You need to include `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters`. What error do you get when adding that?

Comment: I get this back:

Comment: Startup.cs(52,68): error CS1061: 'OutputFormatter' does not contain a definition for 'SupportedMediaType' and no accessible extension method 'SupportedMediaType' accepting a first argument of type 'OutputFormatter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/PracticalApps/NorthwindService/NorthwindService.csproj]

Comment: The property name you're looking for is [SupportedMediaTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.outputformatter.supportedmediatypes?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Formatters_OutputFormatter_SupportedMediaTypes), not SupportedMediaType

Comment: That appeared to work. Thank you for your help!